# Should I use Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

First I say this I have not done before and the application with Sqlite
I'm developing a similar survey project.I want save a string array for user's questions answered and an integer array for answer(there are 5 choice and they are saving to array as 0,1,2,3,4) when user closes the project.
Should I use Sqlite?is there a more logical way?

Comment: Yes...you should use Sqlite..you should insert questions and Answers in that database and after that retrieve from it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say "no", if the stuff that you're saving is pretty simple.
I would use sqlite in case you need some relationalship or "complex" query. In your case you can probably just store everything in the SharedPreferences (if you can tell us an example we can guide you).

You can also consider to write to a file your object (a map, or a list, or whatever), or saving it as json.

```
File file = new File(context.getDir("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), PRESETS);
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
outputStream.writeObject(myObject);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use SQLite when there was a need for a database and complex database stuff but what I can see in your question it is just very simple data storing and you can easily achieve it by just dumping them into XML files in the phone instead of adding SQLite database which adds some overhead. Currently I have an app for data collection which collects alot hell of information and I could easily use XML and now since they clint is asking for twoo much data and complex database stuff and I switch to SQLite. the SQLite version of my app is a bit slower then the XML one. JUST FYI.